# Can a fast internet connection compensate for a slow server?

Tags: bandwidth, speed

If the sever is bottlenecking at `100kB/s` with a bandwidth of `A`, would it bottleneck at any higher speed with a bandwidth of `2A`? In another words, can a fast internet connection compensate for a slow server to any extent?

Comment: We had this exact problem when 1 Gbps ethernet was first coming out. The server bus was limited to 400 Mbps, so if you had more traffic than that toward the server, a lot of it was dropped, and the server could never send out anywhere near that fast. Things have greatly improved on the hardware side, but software can be a problem, and you see evidence of that on [so] from time to time, where a programmer wrote something that simply cannot keep up with the network.

Comment: And even 100M. The ISA bus isn't that fast. (I have a 100/10 ISA card in my collection. No drivers, and NatSemi won't admit to having made it. :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A server cannot become faster when you upgrade its link alone (if the link isn't the bottleneck). The possible throughput is the lower value of local throughput and network throughput.

Answer (score 0):

No .. High  bandwidth internet  connectivity cannot compensate low throughput Server . Tràffic will flow fasters from ISP link and reaches to server  but  beacuse of traffic congestion at server end traffic packets will be queued at server end resulting packet drops and latency and low performance .. The only solution is to increase throughput at server end  resulting avoiding congestion of packets at server end.